# FInd modulus without using modulus operator

Tags: php, logic

Using the modulus operator (`%`), I know I can do the following in PHP:

```
<?php
$a= 17;
$b = 3;
$c = $a % $b;
echo $c; // => 2
?>
```

But an interview question asked how to find it without using the `%` operator to check my logical skills. I tried the following:

```
<?php 
$c = $a/$b; 
$res = $c * $b; 
$output = $a - $res; //2 
?>
```

But this isn't working. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: What do you mean 'without operators'? Presumably you just want `echo 2;`

Comment: @Mike W -->This is my interview question. I tried as 
 <?php
 $c = $a/$b;
 $res = $c * $b;
 $output = $a - $res; //2
 ?>

But interviewer expects me get output without any operator.
he just checks my logical skills. I failed to pass

Comment: Maybe your interviewer likes `reinventing the wheels` concept.

Comment: @Dagon --> My logic fails i am not selected

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? I think Psychie is trying to learn; Asking questions is a good way to do so. I think the question is quite valid and demonstrates *some* effort. Telling him it doesn't have *any resemblance to PHP programming job* doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @PsycheGenie You forgot to get only the integer part of division. Otherwise you would've hit the answer. Check out my answer to see where you've failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to calculate the modulus of a number *without* the modulus operator. Well, this is how it can be done manually:

```
while ($b <= $a) {
    $c = $a - $b;
    $a -= $b;
}
echo $c; // => 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method (without looping, which makes it faster for large numbers being modded by small numbers)

```
<?php
    $a= 17;
    $b = 3;
    $c = ($a / $b - (int)($a / $b)) * $b;
    echo $c; // => 2
?>
```

Speed comparison:

```
Looping time (17 % 3): 0.0000209808349609375
no-Loop time (17 % 3): 0.0000140666961669921875

Looping time (177777777 % 3): 3.370441913604736328125
no-Loop time (177777777 % 3): 0.00000286102294921875
```

Test code ([fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/uepM2R)):

```
<pre>
<?php

    $a= 17;
    $b = 3;
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    while ($b <= $a) {
        $c = $a - $b;
        $a -= $b;
    }
    $endtime = microtime(true);
    echo rtrim(sprintf('Looping time (17 %% 3): %.50F', $endtime - $starttime), "0");

    echo "<br />";

    $a= 17;
    $b = 3;
    $starttime = microtime(true);
$c = ($a / $b - (int)($a / $b)) * $b;
    $endtime = microtime(true);
    echo rtrim(sprintf('no-Loop time (17 %% 3): %.50F', $endtime - $starttime), "0");


echo "<br /><br />";

    $a= 177777777;
    $b = 3;
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    while ($b <= $a) {
        $c = $a - $b;
        $a -= $b;
    }
    $endtime = microtime(true);
    echo rtrim(sprintf('Looping time (177777777 %% 3): %.50F', $endtime - $starttime), "0");

    echo "<br />";

    $a= 177777777;
    $b = 3;
    $starttime = microtime(true);
$c = ($a / $b - (int)($a / $b)) * $b;
    $endtime = microtime(true);
    echo rtrim(sprintf('no-Loop time (177777777 %% 3): %.50F', $endtime - $starttime), "0");
?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both `$a` are `$b` integers...

With math:

```
$c = $a - intval($a / $b) * $b;
```

Demo: https://eval.in/65219

With built-in functions:

```
$c = (int) fmod($a, $b);
$c = (int) bcmod($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a= 17;
$b = 3;
while ($b <= $a) {
$c = $a - $b;
$a = $a - $b;
}
echo $c; // => 2
?>
```

This Will Give The Require Output. Loop Runs Until $a get less than $b. When $a gets the minimum value that will be assigned to $c. That will be the output for getting modulo of two numbers without using division and modulo operator